# efecto scroll en un textview

Tags: android

Me gustaría desarrollar una app sencilla para llevar a cabo un ejemplo.

La app solo constaría de un textview con un texto establecido, y un botón que activara el efecto marquee o scroll lateral.

He estado navegando por internet y ningún ejemplo me ha funcionado.

La peculiaridad de la petición, es que me gustaría que el textview pasara a ser marquee cuando el boton es pulsado, y no antes...

¿se os ocurre alguna manera?

Comment: Hola Sergio, lo mejor sería que compartieras código que ya has intentado, aunque no funcione, para poder ayudarte de una manera más específica.

Comment: basicamente por internet solo he encontrado ejemplos para que un textview sea marquee desde el mismo xml, de los pocos que he podido encontrar que se active el marquee desde codigo ha sido este: http://www.android-examples.com/make-textview-scrollable-in-android-programmatically/ y como digo no me ha funcionado :(